# 8 How do I display "Showing content between date1 and date2" on the current pager item?

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I am creating a list of content with a mini pager. I can't seem to find an option to print the date range of all the nodes being displayed in the current pager item. The content type has a date field. I would like to say "Showing content between date1 and date2" on each pager item based on the date field in the content type.

**Clarification:**
Except the date1 and date2 are the same field. This approach would not print the date range automatically based on a single date field... Let's say I have 100 node items with a NewsDate field. On each page, filter should show the the most recent to the latest date on top of each page. "Showing pages between "date range".

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way for "Showing content between date1 and date2" use the Exposed filters  fields for the "Start date" and "End date" with Is between Operator. According to field created in the content type, From this You can easily filter the content according your filled date and set displayed items in pager.
Hope its helpful to you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Except the date1 and date2 are the same field. This approach would not print the date range automatically based on a single date field... Let's say I have 100 node items with a NewsDate field. On each page, filter should show the the most recent to the latest date on top of each page. "Showing pages between "date range"...